# Saving a page with a <div> including current div style properties

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Background:**

I have a page in where there is a div containing an image. This div can be dragged around and be re-positioned around the page.

**Problem:**

I need to save the page into an HTML file including the current style properties (specifically the width, height, top, and left).Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Thank you!

[image: Movable and Resizable <div>]

Comment: You should do some research and try aout some stuff, then present what you have done; As start help: You first Need to make a decission about how you want to get The Data back to the Server (Ajax or Request Variables)

Comment: What do you mean by `2.I also thought of using javascript but it runs on the client side so javascript is crossed out.`??? Javascript IS a Client Side Language, there are not many alternatives

Comment: Well javascript alone won't do the work. Maybe using it with JQuery would do the trick. Removed #2 anyway.

Comment: JQuery is just an Help to write JS becouse it bundels functions. Everything JQuery can - Javascript can too. But anstosa provided the coorect answer anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to save the entire contents of the client-side page back to the server because it leaves you vulnerable to [injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

It's best to keep track of the minimum set of information required to replicate the state you want to save. In this case, you need to save the position and size of the star.

You can use JS to get these data on the client-side:

```
var star = document.getElementById('star');
var data = {
    width: star.offsetWidth,
    height: star.offsetHeight,
    left: star.offsetLeft,
    top: star.offsetTop
}
```

You can then send these values back to the server using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) ([jQuery makes this easy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/))

```
$.post('/save.php', data);
```

On the server side, write your php file which expects a JSON data object and save those values for later use.

Finally, when the saved page is requested, change the starting location of the star using these values (either by templating into the `style` attribute of the star div, or some other means).

Comment: This would be the best way. The project was just for the purpose of a school project though so I thought that would be the fastest way (regardless of security).